# Container bootstrap color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Recently, I used bootstrap to make my website responsive, as soon as I put the container, it added a Margin, and it has a white color, and it doesn't take the color of the rest of the background, how can I solve this?

[image: Look at margin white]

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
  <section class="lndForm">
    <div class="containerform">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="div2">
          <div class="textCTA">
            <h2 class="title"> Ajudando pessoas comuns a passar na redação ENEM </h2>
            <form action="https://formsubmit.co/rodrigoriosn3@gmail.com" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
              <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://margarethredacoes.com.br/">
              <label for="nome">Nome</label> <br>
              <input type="text" name="NOME" id="" required> <br>
              <label for="email" required>Email</label> <br>
              <input type="email" name="E-MAIL" id="" required> <br>
              <label for="telefone">Telefone</label> <br>
              <input type="text" name="TELEFONE" id="" required>
              <button type="submit" onclick="alerta()">Continuar</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="div1">
          <div class="containerimage">
            <img src="/Imagens/professora.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you really using bootstrap-4? What version exactly? Also, provide a [repro]. I can see no margin-class within your code!

Comment: Yeah, the margin that's im saying is the margin created by Container boostrap class, in white at the print

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question that how you wrote your css. so I am trying to explain to you in my own way.

When you set background color to any section always try to set it on the parent html tag like I set the background color of this section on the section tag `<section class="bg-success">` then if you need margin from both left and right side you can use `container` class in the child block element like this `<div class="container">`. Here is the example

```
<section class="bg-success">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- your content here -->
    <p class="text-light">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

But if you the opposite thing like set the `container` class to the `section` `<section class="container">` and the set background color in the child block element
`<div class="bg-success">` then you will get the background only inside the `container` with left and right side white margin. Like this one

```
   <section class="container">
      <div class="bg-success">
        <!-- your content here -->
        <p class="text-light">
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
```